# How to chain dispatch in ngrx?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, ngrx, ngrx-effects

eg

```
 this.store.dispatch(this.nowChannellistActions.toggleChannel(channel));
 this.store.dispatch(this.playerSearchActions.searchCurrentQuery());
```

In the above code I want the second dispatch to start only after completetion of all reducers and effects of first. dispatch being asynchronus and yet not returning anything and not proving a callback either, I can't easily figure out how to do that.

Comment: just create another effect that catches the first action and trigger the second one

Comment: @Maxime but will that guarantee that the second dispatch occurs after the completion of the first?

Comment: @Maxime What did you mean by "catches the first action", do you mean in reducer of the first action or in the effect of the first action ?

Comment: Within an effect, catch this action `this.nowChannellistActions.toggleChannel(channel)`, do want you want to do in the effect (for example fetch some API or whatever). Still in the effect, once you've got the API response return another action (that will be automatically dispatched by the effect). That action might be `this.playerSearchActions.searchCurrentQuery()` and it would do what you expect

Comment: i can think only by create some kind of reducer that keeps last unique action id. Action creator will allocate this id. So component calls the creator to create the first action, subscribes for store id updates and filter on the first action unique id, as soon event received, dispatch the second action.